# Office 365 Connector does not show up in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, microsoft-teams, office365connectors

I have installed the Office 365 connector:

[image: I have installed the Office 365 connector]

And it doesn't show any tab as "Office 365 Connector" despite many times reinstall and restart:

[image: And it doesnt show any tab as"Office 365 Connector"]

Jenkins v 2.263.2

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried installing Jenkins app from app store in MS teams and then configure your connector?

Comment: I did create a webhook in MS Teams.

Comment: i just found out that it just only not show up in Multi branch pipeline. why is that

Comment: i have same issue here. any updates ?

Answer (score 1):

The UI does not support multibranch pipelines, but must be called by the script.

Vis a vi, you must create a jenkinsfile and manually call the webhookURL within the pipeline.

https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-39745